# lua で文字列の変換を行うには？

Tags: lua

Yamahaルーター（RTX810）にてLuaスクリプトを動かしたいのですが、文字列の扱いで困っています。

下記のように文字列を変換したいです。

**"ANONYMOUS[03]: " → "ANONYMOUS03"**

Luaには `string.match` や `string.gsub` など便利な文字列を扱う関数があるようですが、当方正規表現がうまく扱えず実現できませんでした。

上記の変換をするには、新しく関数を作ることになる気がします。
知見のある方でお力添えいただける方はいらっしゃらないでしょうか？

ちなみに、参照した記事は下記です。
http://xn--pckzexbx21r8q9b.net/lua_tips/?lua_reference_lib_regex

Comment: Lua の文字列操作で利用できるパターンマッチングはあくまで「パターンマッチング」という独自の機能であって，一般に言う「正規表現」とは異なるものです．念のため．

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string.gsub` なら

```
s = "ANONYMOUS[03]: "
s = string.gsub(s, "(%w*)%[(%w*)%]: ", "%1%2")
print(s)
```

結果

```
ANONYMOUS03
```

となります。